# Make CronTab not asking for id_rsa keyword when running in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, cron, git, zsh

I like to do some `git pull` inside a script and see see output of it. So I made up this cronjob to test:

```
DISPLAY=:0
* * * * * mike /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x zsh -c "/var/www/up.sh; zsh" --window-with-profile=/home/mike/.profile
```

Running the cronjob within an own shell, keep open after that and for god sake use me as the owner and my profile. It is the crontab for the user "mike" also.

But this keeps nagging me about the id_rsa keyword everytime for every project it shall do a pull in.

How can I get rid of that and make it use the `id_rsa`?

The crontab will later on always run when I am logged in.

Comment: Why not just use a key without passphrase? You can remove an existing passphrase with `ssh-keygen -p -N '' -f id_rsa`.